# Validating sections of a form

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, jquery-validate

I've broken my form up into divs and using Next buttons to shop and hide those sections.
I am also using jQuery Validation Plugin to do all the validation for me.

What I need to know is how to validate section by section. So this is what I have

1. Personal Information
2. Address details
3. Project Information
4. Terms and conditions

2,3,and 4 are hidden by default to make the form less daunting.

Clicking on the next button of Personal Information will hide this div and show the Address Details and so on.

The very last screen has the submit form button which then would validate the entire form normally but I need to validate each section before the user moves on.

Here's what I thought should have worked:

**CSS**

```
   .project-address {display:none;}
```

**HTML**

```
   <form class="wpcf7">
      <div class="project-details">
        <h2>Project details</h2>
        <label>Project name: </label><input type="text" class="reg-project-name" size="40" value="" name="projectName">
      <div class="back-next"><span class="reg-next-button">Next</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="project-address">
        <h2>Project address</h2>
        <label>Project address:</label><input type="text" class="reg-project-address" size="40" value="" name="projectAddress">
      <div class="back-next"><span class="reg-next-button">Next</span></div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
    //clicking the next button hides this section and shows the next section
    jQuery('.project-details .reg-next-button').click(function() {

        // jQuery(".project-details").slideUp();
        // jQuery('.project-address').slideDown();          

        jQuery('.reg-project-name').validate({
            debug: true,
            rules: {
                projectName: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                projectName: "Please give your project a name",
            }
            });

             });
```

**EDIT: Have tried to validate one element like this.**

```
       jQuery('.project-details .reg-next-button').click(function() {

        // jQuery(".project-details").slideUp();
        // jQuery('.project-funding').slideDown();          
        var validator = jQuery( ".wpcf7-form" ).validate();
        validator.element( ".reg-project-name" );

    });
```

**EDIT:**
If I click on the Next button, I need the form elements to be validated in that div before moving on which is not happening. i.e the form elements are not being validated..

Any thoughts?
Many thanks.

Comment: what is the problem? Where are u stuck?

Comment: Hi Akki. Added an EDIT above, thanks

Comment: can u post your html or best is to set up a fiddle. We are not getting idea from the code.

Comment: I worked through this problem once--it's a major pain.  I don't have the code any more.  But, basically, you have to write a validation function that loops through all child elements from a certain start point and call the .validate() method on them.

Comment: Fiddle password reminder is down. I've added more HTML.

Comment: Going to try this next http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element

Comment: If you can use multiple form tag on same page then you can do this easily. as @rituraj-ratan demo link.

Comment: use submit button in your form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, forget about wrapping `.validate()` inside of any click handlers... it just doesn't work like that.  One issue is that `.validate()` is not a method for "testing" the form's validity.  Rather, `.validate()` is only the method for *initializing* the plugin on the form.  You would do it *once* on page load, because any subsequent calls to `.validate()` are ignored.

To test the form programatically with the jQuery Validate plugin, you use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) which triggers a test and returns a boolean.

When I create multi-step forms, I use a unique set of `<form>` tags for each section.

Then I use `.valid()` to test the section before moving to the next.  *(Don't forget to first initialize the plugin; call `.validate()`, on all forms on DOM ready.)*

Then on the last section, I use `.serialize()` on each form and concatenate them into a data query string to be submitted.

Something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form1').validate({
        // rules
    });

    $('#form2').validate({
        // rules
    });

    $('#form3').validate({
        // rules,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
           // serialize and join data for all forms
           // ajax submit
           return false;
        }
    });

    $('#gotoStep2').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#form1').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 2
        }
    });

    $('#gotoStep3').on('click', function() {
        if ($('#form2').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 3
        }
    });

    // there is no third click handler since the plugin takes care of this with the
    // built-in submitHandler callback function on the last form.

});
```

Important to remember that my `click` handlers above are not using `type="submit"` buttons.  These are regular buttons, either *outside* of the `form` tags or `type="button"`.

Only the button on the very last form is a regular `type="submit"` button.  That is because I am leveraging the plugin's built-in `submitHandler` callback function on only the very last form.

**"Proof of Concept" DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/N9UpD/**

Also, see for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975061/594235

Comment: Thanks Sparky. I will most certainly implement this and try it. It looks promising!

Comment: This did the job! Thanks Sparky.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`valid`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) method on a selection of elements that you wish to validate.

### Working Example:

```js
// First, set up validator
$('#projectForm').validate({
  debug: true,
  rules: {
    projectName: "required"
  },
  messages: {
    projectName: "Please give your project a name",
  }
});

//clicking the next button hides the current section and shows the next section
$('.project-details .reg-next-button').click(function() {
    // Get the form that this button lives in
    var form = $(this).closest("form");
    // Get the validator object for the form
    var validator = form.data("validator");
    // Get the section that we're currently validating.  May need to modify this depending on the structure of your DOM
    var section = $(this).closest("div");
    // Get all controls (input, textarea, select, etc) in the section
    var fields = section.find(":input");
    if (fields.valid()){
      console.log("Valid!");
      // Hide this section...
      section.toggle();
      // And show the next section
      section.next().toggle();
    }
});
```

```css
.project-address {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="projectForm">
  <div class="project-details">
    <h2>Project details</h2>
    <label>Project name: </label>
    <input type="text" class="reg-project-name" size="40" value="" name="projectName">
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="reg-next-button">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="project-address">
    <h2>Project address</h2>
    <label>Project address:</label><input type="text" class="reg-project-address" size="40" value="" name="projectAddress">
    <br>
    <button class="reg-next-button">Next</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

See this Codepen: http://codepen.io/alexweissman/pen/Wragog

Comment: This - var fields = section.find(":input"); if (fields.valid()){}
got me where I needed to go.  Thanks!!

Comment: +1 for this answer, since it's actually using only one form, validation by sections. No need to create multiple forms.

Comment: Great solution and should be marked as the correct answer, however this bit can be removed from the code: `var validator = form.data("validator");`

Answer (score 0):

it works in **form** tag

**in html** set like below structure

```
<form class="project-details">

   <h2>Project details</h2>

   <label>Project name: </label>
   <div class="back-next"><span class="reg-next-button">Next</span></div>


 </form>
```

for demo see **[here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/)**

Comment: Thanks Rituraj but this still doesn't tell me how I would validate certain fields on the click of a button to go to the next page?

Comment: But surely that would try to submit the form?

Comment: I've improved my html/css a little, hope that helps explain things a bit better?