# jQuery Validate : Validating specific group

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am attempting to use `jQuery Validate`, and one of my requirements is to validate some specific groups as they go through a wizard user interface. I cannot seem to locate the jQuery Validate documentation for this feature, though, and can only find very vague references to it online.

My declaration is essentially like this;

```
form.validate({
                    groups: {
                        raceGroup: "race",
                        identityGroup: "name gender age"
                    },
                    rules: {
                        race: {
                            required: true,
                        },
                        gender: {
                            valueNotEquals: "Select Gender ...",
                            required: true
                        },
                        name: {
                            pattern: "^(?!.*[ ]{2})(?!.*[']{2})(?!.*[-]{2})(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 \p{L}'-]{3,64}$)$"
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        race: {
                            required: "this is a required for your character."
                        },
                        name: {
                            pattern: "You have entered an invalid name."
                        },
                        gender: {
                            valueNotEquals: "You must select a valid gender.",
                            required: "You must select a valid gender."
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Okay, so I have the groups defined ... but now what? How can I check if everything within a group is valid? (or invalid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
groups: {
    raceGroup: "race",
    identityGroup: "name gender age"
},
```

> *"How can I check if everything within a group is valid? (or invalid)"*

You don't.  This is not how the `groups` option works.

Using the `groups` option, you are merely grouping together several error messages into one.  Example: if you have a group of fields, each using the `require_from_group` rule (*any* 'one or more' fields out of the group are required), the `groups` option will ensure that only one message appears instead of repeated next to every input.

There is no defined option or standardized setup for creating validation groups.

If you're trying to do a stepped form, there are various approaches.

When I create multi-step forms, I use a unique set of `<form>` tags for each section.  Then I use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) to test the section before moving to the next.  *(Don't forget to first initialize the plugin; call `.validate()`, on all forms on DOM ready.)*

Then on the last section, I use `.serialize()` on each form and concatenate them into a data query string to be submitted.

Something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form1').validate({ // initialize form 1
        // rules
    });

    $('#gotoStep2').on('click', function() { // go to step 2
        if ($('#form1').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 2 and hide step 1
        }
    });

    $('#form2').validate({ // initialize form 2
        // rules
    });

    $('#gotoStep3').on('click', function() { // go to step 3
        if ($('#form2').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 3 and hide step 2
        }
    });

    $('#form3').validate({ // initialize form 3
        // rules,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
           // serialize and join data for all forms
           // ajax submit
           return false;
        }
    });

    // there is no third click handler since the plugin takes care of this with the
    // built-in submitHandler callback function on the last form.

});
```

Important to remember that my `click` handlers above are not using `type="submit"` buttons.  These are regular buttons, either *outside* of the `form` tags or `type="button"`.

Only the button on the very last form is a regular `type="submit"` button.  That is because I am leveraging the plugin's built-in `submitHandler` callback function on only the very last form.

**"Proof of Concept" DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/N9UpD/**

Also, see for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17975061/594235

Comment: This did work, but not in the exact way you described. Or rather, the way you described works, but it is not exactly how I solved it. Instead, I used `currentPage.find(':input').valid()` to determine if an entire 'part' of my wizard was valid. Which is similar to the principle you laid out right here. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: but reading the canonical documentation here: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate, under the section for Rules, I see "Key is the name of an element (or a group of checkboxes/radio buttons)", which leads me to believe that one can define a rule for a group.  no?

Comment: @ekkis, **no**.  A "group" of radio buttons or checkboxes sharing the same `name` has nothing to do with this question, which is about the `groups` option, which merely lumps messages together; and that has absolutely nothing to do with declaring rules:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups