# jQuery nested phone number validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, nested-loops, phone-number

Does anyone know how to use the jQuery validation plug-in while looping through inputs?  The only way I know how to make the validation plug-in work is through a submit request.  However, I am working on a multi-part form that validates on each step of the form and simply highlights required fields as the user moves through.  I would like to add validation to this process as well, just not sure how to do it.  Ideally, I'd like to validate more than just phone numbers, maybe email format and reg exp as well.  Here the code I'm currently using:

```
function validateStep(step) {
  if(step == fieldsetCount) return;

  var error = 1;
  var hasError = false;
  $('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(step) +')').find(':input:not(button)').each(function(){
    var $this       = $(this);
    var valueLength = jQuery.trim($this.val()).length;

    if(valueLength == ''){
      if($(this).hasClass('req')) {
        hasError = true;
        $this.addClass('hasError');
      }
      else
        $this.removeClass('hasError');
    } else {
      $this.removeClass('hasError');
    }
  });  
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried calling [`valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) on the elements of one step instead of the entire form?

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is not making a whole lot of sense to me.  If you want to use the jQuery Validation plugin, then validation is handled automatically, you do not need to manually loop through any inputs.

As far as multi-step forms, there are many possible approaches.  I prefer to use an individual `form` element for each step.  Then I use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) to test the section before moving to the next.  *(Don't forget to first initialize the plugin; call `.validate()`, on all forms on DOM ready.)*

Then on the last section, I use `.serialize()` on each form and concatenate them into a data query string to be submitted.

Something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form1').validate({ // initialize form 1
        // rules
    });

    $('#gotoStep2').on('click', function() { // go to step 2
        if ($('#form1').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 2 and hide step 1
        }
    });

    $('#form2').validate({ // initialize form 2
        // rules
    });

    $('#gotoStep3').on('click', function() { // go to step 3
        if ($('#form2').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 3 and hide step 2
        }
    });

    $('#form3').validate({ initialize form 3
        // rules,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
           // serialize and join data for all forms
           var data = $('#form1').serialize() + '&' + $('#form2').serialize() + '&' + $(form).serialize()
           // ajax submit
           return false; // block regular form submit action
        }
    });

    // there is no third click handler since the plugin takes care of this 
    // with the built-in submitHandler callback function on the last form.

});
```

Important to remember that my `click` handlers above are not using `type="submit"` buttons.  These are regular buttons, either *outside* of the `form` tags or `type="button"`.

Only the button on the very last form is a regular `type="submit"` button.  That is because I am leveraging the plugin's built-in `submitHandler` callback function on only the very last form.

**"Proof of Concept" DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/j8vUt/**

See this for reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546698/594235