# How to validate form more than once with Jquery Validate

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am working on this wizard that have **5 steps** but **a single form**, the intent is to process the data on a single server request when the user hits the **Finish** button.

I am trying to use Jquery Validate plugin to validate each step **separately**, my original idea was to reinitialize the plugin every time the user clicks next, like that:

```
function validateStepOne(){

    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            x: "required"
     }}); 

    if(!$("#form").valid()){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

function validateStepTwo(){
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
        y : "required",
    }}); 

    if(!$("#form").valid()){
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But that doesnt seems to work because **on second+ steps the forms is always marked as valid**, so I am wondering how can I reset the validation plugin to be able to validate the same form more than once.. Any help is welcome

Comment: Try to remove the validation with: $('#formid').removeData('validator'); between the validations. Or can you have multiple forms in your page with unique validation?

Comment: You can **not** reinitialize the plugin.  It can only be initialized once on the form.  Your only options are to break it up into five different `form` containers OR use the `.rules()` method to activate/deactivate rules as needed.  Otherwise, the plugin will ignore hidden fields by default, and for some people, this is good enough for this scenario.

Comment: See this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19546698/594235

Comment: @Sparky I ended up figuring out that the hidden fields are ignored, so I just inserted all the rules on a single validation method, as you suggested above, anyway if you like to create an answer I can for sure accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not reinitialize the plugin. It can only be initialized once on the form. Your options are to break it up into five different `form` containers OR use the `.rules()` method to activate/deactivate rules as needed.

Otherwise, hidden fields are ignored by default.  So typically on a multi-step form, when the fields in the non-active tabs are hidden, they are no longer validated.  This is the approach many people will take depending on the type of multi-step form.

Comment: Worked with all rules on same validate() call, since hidden fields are ignored. Thanks for letting me know :)